# My JOGL camera rotates instead of looking right and left

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to write an FPS like camera following [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/) tutorial. But when I move my mouse left and right, instead of looking left and right, the camera rotates.

The `sphericalToCartesian` function I'm using function comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391776/cant-limit-the-camera-pitch-angle-between-90%C2%BA-90%C2%BA-in-opengl-using-vectors) post.

My camera class:

```
private static final float FOVY = 60f, ZNEAR = .1f, ZFAR = 2000f;

private Mat4 projectionMatrix;

// start out at origin (0,0,0)
private Vec3 position = new Vec3();

// horizontal angle in radians: toward -Z
private float horizontalAngle = (float) FastMath.PI;
// NOTE: tutorial says 0 is horizon
// vertical angle in radians: π/2, look at the horizon
private float verticalAngle = (float) (FastMath.PI / 2.0f);

private float mouseSpeed = 0.01f;

private Vec3 sphericalToCartesian(float yaw, float pitch) {
    return new Vec3(
            (float) (FastMath.cos(pitch) * FastMath.sin(yaw)),
            (float) FastMath.sin(pitch),
            (float) (FastMath.cos(pitch) * FastMath.cos(yaw))
        );
}

public FPSCamera(Observer o) {
    addObserver(o);
}

/**
 * Called in GLEventListener.display() and sent to shader with
 * glUniformMatrix4fv
 * 
 * @return MPV matrix
 */
public Mat4 getMVPMatrix() {
    Vec3 frontVector = sphericalToCartesian(horizontalAngle, verticalAngle);
    Vec3 rightVector = sphericalToCartesian((float) (horizontalAngle + FastMath.PI / 2.0f), 0f);
    Vec3 upVector = rightVector.cross(frontVector);

    Mat4 viewMatrix = Matrices.lookAt(position, position.add(frontVector), upVector);

    return projectionMatrix.multiply(viewMatrix);
}

/**
 * Called in GLEventListener.reshape()
 * 
 * @param aspect The aspect ratio
 */
public void setPerspective(float aspect) {
    projectionMatrix = Matrices.perspective(FOVY, aspect, ZNEAR, ZFAR);
}

/**
 * Key and mouse listeners will notify the camera when something happens by
 * calling this method.
 */
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    if (o instanceof FPSKeyController) {
        final FPSKeyController.Direction[] dirs = (FPSKeyController.Direction[]) arg;

        Vec3 right = sphericalToCartesian((float) (horizontalAngle + FastMath.PI / 2.0f), 0f);
        Vec3 front = sphericalToCartesian(horizontalAngle, verticalAngle);

        // Move forward and backward
        if (dirs[0] == FPSKeyController.Direction.FORWARD) {
            position = position.add(front);
        } else if (dirs[0] == FPSKeyController.Direction.BACKWARD) {
            position = position.subtract(front);
        }
        // Strafe left and right
        if (dirs[1] == FPSKeyController.Direction.RIGHT) {
            position = position.subtract(right);
        } else if (dirs[1] == FPSKeyController.Direction.LEFT) {
            position = position.add(right);
        }
    } else if (o instanceof FPSMouseController) {
        final FPSMouseController.Direction[] dirs = (FPSMouseController.Direction[]) arg;

        if (dirs[0] == FPSMouseController.Direction.LEFT) {
            // Look left
            horizontalAngle -= mouseSpeed;
            // Let angle range from -2π to 2π
            if (horizontalAngle < -FastMath.PI * 2) {
                horizontalAngle = 0;
            }
        } else if (dirs[0] == FPSMouseController.Direction.RIGHT) {
            // Look right
            horizontalAngle += mouseSpeed;
            // Let angle range from -2π to 2π
            if (horizontalAngle > FastMath.PI * 2) {
                horizontalAngle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (dirs[1] == FPSMouseController.Direction.UP) {
            // Look up
            // Stop the camera from looking more than straight up
            if (verticalAngle + mouseSpeed <= FastMath.PI) {
                verticalAngle += mouseSpeed;
            }
        } else if (dirs[1] == FPSMouseController.Direction.DOWN) {
            // Look down
            // Stop the camera from looking more than straight down
            if (verticalAngle - mouseSpeed >= 0) {
                verticalAngle -= mouseSpeed;
            }

        }
    }
    // input is guaranteed to change the camera, so we can always update the view
    setChanged();
    // repaint() and eventually GLEventListener.display() are called at the observer
    notifyObservers();
}
```

I think my problem is the `verticalAngle`, in the tutorial it's `0` to look at the horizon. I have to change it to `π/2 radians` to look at the horizon. When I look straight down, I can look right and left.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I move my mouse left and right, instead of looking left and right, the camera rotates"? Maybe the tutorial and your FPS camera use different reference marks or axis orientations. Personally, I don't see the interest of reinventing the wheel (except for learning purposes), there are already working FPS cameras implemented in JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation and JMonkeyEngine.

Comment: @gouessej By rotate I mean like instead if panning your head right and left, you turn your head so it touches your shoulder. This is indeed for learning purposes by the way.

Comment: @gouessej Could the problem be that my data represents the Z axis as up and down, while openGL thinks it is forward and backwards?

Comment: Maybe the demo doesn't use the same up vector than you, this is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite right gouessej, Valve uses Z as up, while openGL uses Y.

I got around the problem by rotating the whole world like this:

```
private Mat4 modelMatrix = Matrices.rotate(HALF_PI, new Vec3(1,0,0));
```

and then multiplying the view and projection matrix by this new model-matrix in `getMVPMatrix()`:

```
return projectionMatrix.multiply(viewMatrix).multiply(modelMatrix);
```

Making the MVP matrix an actual `Model`, `View` and `Projection` matrix. Before only the `View` and `Projection` matrices were defined.

Thank you for your time,

Blight

Comment: Good job. Valve isn't alone to do that, I had to do something similar when importing MD2 (Quake 2) models too.